# Restaurar base em container com Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

Estou usando um container com postgres em um servidor EC2 e quero restaurar uma base neste container via comando linux. Alguma dica?

Estava tentando da seguinte forma:

```
sudo docker exec -t postgres_94 pg_restore -c -U postgres > minha_base.backup
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver executando comando através do docker-compose:

```
sudo docker exec -i app_postgres_94_1 pg_restore --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "database_name" --verbose < ~/minha_base.backup
```

Comment: Estava precisando disso, obrigado! Marca sua resposta como a certa > http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer